# How to create a p2sh transaction with a scriptsig of OP_true?

Tags: script, python, input-script, opcodes

How can I create a p2sh transaction with a scriptsig containing OP_TRUE only, removing the need for a digital signature, which will be broadcasted and mined?

Also could some one provide an example of such a transaction?

Comment: @Michael Folkson I see the tag `bitcoin-core-development` was added by you, but I don't understand how it's related to the question, can you explain?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad: Not sure, it was a while back! Think I thought it was functional test related but removed now :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have [an example](https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/da58f6688b0727a7f1bf3eec899099bde1f18b9c7099f9d2c79556db238e623d) of a transaction spending from a P2PKH output and creating a P2SH output with an OP_1.

And here you have [the counterpart](https://www.blockstream.info/testnet/tx/839b903b9f79c3372792ceb95917047c46d1b919ed1f6471f5a19d7c865ab32c), a transaction spending from the first one (with an input script '0151') and generating a P2PKH output.

I've created both using a Python library i'm coauthor of. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/sr-gi/bitcoin_tools).

Comment: I've added new transactions including fees to ensure that they end up in a block.

Comment: Does the output script you use to fund the p2sh transaction always have to be OP_HAS160 (hash) OP_EQUAL ?

Comment: Yes, that's the structure of any P2SH output script.

Comment: Could a transaction like that be created on the mainnet?

Comment: Sure. However you should be careful, anyone will be able to redeem it.

Comment: Would the transaction with scriptsig 0151 be considered standard or non standard?

Comment: Standard AFAIK, it's just a push of data.

Comment: So once the output script you are using as your input is OP_HASH160 (hash) OP_EQUAL , you can create a p2sh transaction with scriptsig OP_TRUE that doesn't require a digital signature?

Comment: You're messing around the concepts a little bit. If you are spending an UTXO of type P2SH that encapsulates the hash of an OP_True, you can create a P2SH transaction that spends it just by pushing a 1 to the stack.

Comment: So how can you know if it encapsulates the hash of OP_TRUE and what does a hash of OP_TRUE  look like?

Comment: `has160(A) = hash_A` no matter how many times you compute it. So the hash of OP_True will always be `da1745e9b549bd0bfa1a569971c77eba30cd5a4b`

Comment: So if the utxo doesn't encapsulate OP_TRUE, is there any other op code or combination of op codes that can be used to create a transaction that can be broadcasted and mined?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter the op_code combination. You can create for examples a P2SH encapsulating an OP_2 OP_EQUAL, and then redeem it with a push of 2. There are many combinations that do not imply a signature.

Comment: So is there any op code or combination of opcodes that will make a  transaction valid regardless of what the output script encapsulates and if not, how can you determine what the output script encapsultes in order to create a scriptsig with the necessary op codes?

Comment: Updated links to blockstream.info as prior block explorer links have been taken down