# How can I create an anyone-can-spend output?

Tags: transactions, validation, p2pkh, anyone-can-spend

How can I create an anyone-can-spend transaction using p2pkh outputs?

Also how would such a transaction in hex look like?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a P2PKH output, it's not anyone-can-spend. P2PKH implies there is a public key that needs to sign for spending.

You can use a P2SH or P2WSH output which sends to an `OP_TRUE` script, though.

You can also manually craft a transaction with a scriptPubKey that is literally `OP_TRUE`. No address corresponds to such an output, so you couldn't use off the shelf wallet software for it.

Comment: So how can i create an anyone can spend transaction?

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: You also have how the transaction will look like (the P2SH Pieter referred to) in a question you asked a few days ago: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72773/30668

Answer (score 1):

For a P2PKH anyone-can-spend, just send to the address 1BgGZ9tcN4rm9KBzDn7KprQz87SZ26SAMH -- its private key is the integer 1, or in WIF format, KwDiBf89QgGbjEhKnhXJuH7LrciVrZi3qYjgd9M7rFU73sVHnoWn. Anyone can spend from this address since the private key is known to all.

Comment: I don't think "the private key is known" is actually the answer he's looking for.